# IonToggle firing twice in React-based Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

In the following block of code, the `IonToggle` is firing twice for some unknown reason. I had it already replaced with a normal `button` and it works fine. If I keep the `IonToggle` and remove the line `setUpdating(true)` it also works fine.

Is it some known bug, or is there something wrong with this code.

```
import { AppContext } from './../AppContextProvider';

const LightController: React.FC<InterfaceLamp> = ({ id, color, brightness, turnedOn }) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [isUpdating, setUpdating] = useState(false);
  const isMount = useIsMount();

  const handleUpdateToggle = async (isToggled: boolean) => {
    lightService.toggleLight(state.api, id, isToggled, state.auth.username, 
    state.auth.password).then((res) => {
      if (!res.error) {
        [...]
        dispatch({
          key: 'devices',
          data: devices,
        })
      }
      setUpdating(false);
    })
  }

 const handleToggle = (isToggled: boolean) => {
    setUpdating(true);
    handleUpdateToggle(isToggled);
  }

  return (
    <div className="c-light">
      <Loader isLoading={isUpdating} message={"Updating devices"} onClose={() => { }} />
      <div className="c-light__controls">
        <div className="c-light__toggle">
          <IonItem lines={"none"}>
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleToggle(!turnedOn)}>toggle</button>
            <IonToggle checked={turnedOn} onIonChange={(e) => handleToggle(e.detail.checked)}/>
          </IonItem>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LightController;
```

Answer (score 0):

`value="true"`

why are you setting the value here? dont think it is necessary

Comment: This was only for debugging. I will update the code. The problem still persists though.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ionic React v5.5.0, IonToggle and IonCheckbox have still got the same issue.

The simplest workaround is to add an onClick event listener to the IonItem component that usually wraps the IonToggle component. (Alternately, use any other wrapper component with onClick.) This approach makes it possible to keep the native-looking IonToggle.